# Why these threads no started and ended orderly?how to fix it?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm a newbie in Java multiply Thread and I stuck in my research for a exercise what I find from a tutorial:

Imagine this scene: I have an 100hp gareen, and it have been attacked by 10 times,and my code is:

```
public class Hero{
    public String name;
    public float hp;
    public int damage;

    public Hero(){
        
    }
    public Hero(String name,float hp,int damage){
        this.name = name;
        this.hp = hp;
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public synchronized void hurt(){
            this.hp -= 1;
    }

    public void recover(){
            this.hp += 1;
    }

    public void attackHero(Hero h) {
        try {

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        h.hp-=damage;
        System.out.format("%s attacked %s, %s'hp become %.0f%n",name,h.name,h.name,h.hp);

        if(h.isDead())
            System.out.println(h.name +"dead！");
    }

    public boolean isDead() {
        return 0>=hp?true:false;
    }

}
```

```
public class TestHero {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hero gareen = new Hero("Gareen", 100, 10);
        System.out.printf("Initial HP of Gareen: %f\n",gareen.hp);
        int N = 10;
        Thread[] hurtThreads = new Thread[N];
        Thread[] coverThreads = new Thread[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
                gareen.hurt();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: " + gareen.hp);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ended");
            });

            t1.start();
            System.out.println(t1.getName() + " started");
            hurtThreads[i] = t1;
        }

// In this time, all threads have been spawned and unstart
        for(Thread t : hurtThreads){
            try {
                t.join();
                System.out.println(t.getName() + " joined ");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Now, Gareen's HP: " + gareen.hp);
    
    }
}
```

In my imagine, it should be like（I spaced the result () for readability）:

```
Initial HP of Gareen: 100.000000
// started and joined will be printed first because they all are sychronized code
Thread-0 started
Thread-1 started
Thread-2 started
Thread-3 started
Thread-4 started
Thread-5 started
Thread-6 started
Thread-7 started
Thread-8 started
Thread-9 started
//
Thread-0 joined 
Thread-1 joined 
Thread-2 joined 
Thread-3 joined 
Thread-4 joined 
Thread-5 joined 
Thread-6 joined 
Thread-7 joined 
Thread-8 joined 
Thread-9 joined 
//
// the thread will be started and ended orderly
Thread-0: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 99.0
Thread-1: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 98.0
Thread-2: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 97.0
Thread-3: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 96.0
Thread-5: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 95.0
Thread-6: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 94.0
Thread-7: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 93.0
Thread-8: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 92.0
Thread-9: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 91.0
Thread-10: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 90.0
//
Thread-0 ended
Thread-1 ended
Thread-2 ended
Thread-3 ended
Thread-4 ended
Thread-5 ended
Thread-6 ended
Thread-7 ended
Thread-8 ended
Thread-9 ended
//
Now, Gareen's HP: 90.0
```

But the reality is(same, spaced for readability):

```java
Initial HP of Gareen: 100.000000
Thread-0 started
Thread-1 started
Thread-2 started
Thread-3 started
Thread-4 started
Thread-5 started
Thread-6 started
Thread-7 started
Thread-8 started
Thread-9 started
    
Thread-3: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 96.0
Thread-7: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 92.0
Thread-2: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 97.0
Thread-4: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 95.0
Thread-1: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 98.0
Thread-6: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 93.0
Thread-0: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 99.0
Thread-9: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 90.0
Thread-8: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 91.0
Thread-5: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 94.0
    
Thread-3 ended
Thread-6 ended
Thread-2 ended
Thread-4 ended
Thread-1 ended
Thread-7 ended
Thread-9 ended
Thread-8 ended
Thread-0 ended
Thread-5 ended
    
Thread-0 joined 
Thread-1 joined 
Thread-2 joined 
Thread-3 joined 
Thread-4 joined 
Thread-5 joined 
Thread-6 joined 
Thread-7 joined 
Thread-8 joined 
Thread-9 joined 
Now, Gareen's HP: 90.0
```

I don't understand **why the join() always end after which called thread ends** but know that it blocked the last statement `System.out.println("Now, Gareen's HP: " + gareen.hp);`

to make sure it will be printed at the end.

According printed result, seems like though **every threads start in almost same time, but their do things and ends are all different.**  Another weird part is I find that the changed HP is correctly cope with the thread tag like `t0 - 99`,`t2 - 98`, ...`t9 - 90`, but their don't print in descend orderly, I spent very long time to realized a possible reason:  **What message the system prints don't match what actually the threads doing,**

I even find that the two print statements in defined Thread don't run orderly when I delete the `Thread.sleep`() , seems like **the code in Threads actually don't run in order. I'm always think that Thread just a function that don't run orderly with synchronize code outside.**

```java
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
                gareen.hurt();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: " + gareen.hp);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ended");
            });
          

            t1.start();
            System.out.println(t1.getName() + " started");
            hurtThreads[i] = t1;
        }
```

```java
Initial HP of Gareen: 100.000000
Thread-0 started
Thread-1 started
Thread-2 started
Thread-3 started
Thread-4 started
Thread-5 started
Thread-6 started
Thread-7 started
Thread-8 started
Thread-9 started
    
Thread-5: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 94.0
Thread-5 ended
Thread-3: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 96.0
Thread-8: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 91.0
Thread-9: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 90.0
Thread-9 ended
Thread-7: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 92.0
Thread-7 ended
Thread-0: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 99.0
Thread-0 ended
Thread-3 ended
Thread-8 ended
Thread-2: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 97.0
Thread-6: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 93.0
Thread-4: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 95.0
Thread-6 ended
Thread-1: Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: 98.0
Thread-0 joined 
Thread-2 ended
Thread-1 ended
Thread-4 ended
    
Thread-1 joined 
Thread-2 joined 
Thread-3 joined 
Thread-4 joined 
Thread-5 joined 
Thread-6 joined 
Thread-7 joined 
Thread-8 joined 
Thread-9 joined 
Now, Gareen's HP: 90.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Now I'm completely confused,  what cause these phenomenon, and can I possible to realize the scene I imagined ?

Comment: What is “100hp gareen”?

Comment: @Basil from what I can glean, Gareen is the character, hp is health points, and 100 is the number of health points Gareen starts with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that threads execute in a set order. You would just use standard synchronous code for that.

If you just want to make the health code down in a linear fashion outside the main thread, then use 1 Thread and execute all code within that. Example:

```
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                gareen.hurt();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": Gareen lost 1 HP,now his HP: " + gareen.hp);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ended");
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        System.out.println(t1.getName() + " started");
```

This would achieve the result of reducing the health on a background thread so that you can simultaneously update the UI, sounds, etc

---

Another solution would be to use a Singleton for the Hero object - https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton and a synchronized lock on the object. However this would not produce a significantly different result from the first solution.

---

> don't understand why the join() always end after which called thread ends

`Thread.join()` in your scenario is used to block the main thread until the thread you called `.join()` on completes.